# getting regression function from formula in R

Tags: r, formula, regression

I am just trying to write an R function which gives me the regression function from this expression: y~(k,l,m,n). These letters represent parameters in a nonlinear function. This R function is supposed to extract the regression function from the model when I write the model in closed form(y~()). It can be any nonlinear function with two or more parameters. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Actually I have not tried anything. I just took a look at the nls function in R. I tried to understand how it was handled in this function.

Comment: I need something that R does as in the below: cll <- formula[[length(formula)]]
func <- get(as.character(cll[[1L]]))
if (!is.null(pn <- attr(func, "pnames"))) 
as.character(as.list(match.call(func, call = cll))[-1L][pn])

Comment: What do you mean by *extract*? Do you mean fit? or are you extracting from an `nls` object, or trying to write your own version of `nls`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes I am trying to write my own nls function using gauss-newton algorithm. I am OK with the algorithm part but could not figure out how to make the formula run. When someone write formula in closed form my function should convert it to a formula. It can be any nonlinear formula. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your sticking point is getting a formula that will parse

you can't just have `y~(a,b,d)`, you need some function name, ie `y ~ f(a, b, d)`

Then you can use `all.vars` to extract the variable names and create model matrices and write your fitting function

eg

```
all.vars(y ~ f(a,b,d))

## [1] "y" "a" "b" "d"

# get the response

as.character(y ~ f(a,b,d))[2]
## [1] "y"
```

You can use these to extract the objects from the search path

Comment: Many thanks! My apologies. I forgot to put function just before parenthesis.